# How can I send the second set of loop after getting response of the first set of loop in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

My application is calling ajax in every 5 seconds. I am testing with a load of 3500 users. That means 3500 users are calling ajax in every 5 seconds

Application setup- ajax is called in an interval of 5 seconds only after getting a response from the first ajax. Mean first ajax is called the request is processed by server and give response and then 5 seconds and then next ajax is called.

My jmeter setup- Am using loop controller and constant timer(5 seconds) inside the loop controller. So the request is being send my jmeter constanly in every 5 seconds irrespective of the response. So every 5 seconds 3500 users is being called with or without getting response.

My expectation: I want to call ajax request only once I gets the response from each threads of 3500 users. How can I do that in Jmeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the prompt reply. This actually worked. But, I found out much simple method. Added a beanshell postprocessor as a child of the ajax request and added a script `Thread.sleep(5000);`. Which did the same behavior I explained above

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use a "**IF Controller"** in Jmeter to check the response of the previous request and control the rest of the flow accordingly.

For example, use `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` function as the condition of the controller, which checks if the previous request was successful before executing the next request.

More information can be found under "Tip #5 - Use the ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} to Check Transactional Requests" in [1]

[1] https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage

Hope this helps.